# Elastic Beanstalk CLI upload version without deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

Is there a way with EB CLI to upload a zip package to the environment but not actually deploy it? This can be done on the web console but I would like to have the output of each build in the CI server to be uploaded to Elastic Beanstalk via EB CLI but only selected builds actually be deployed (this step will be manual in the web console)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The EB CLI does not have the functionality for this process. I would suggest using the [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-application-version.html) to push the local zip into S3 then to upload using the Create Application Version method directly, like this:

```
aws s3 cp app.zip s3://staging-bucket

aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name app-name --version-label deploy-app --source-bundle S3Bucket=staging-bucket,S3Key=app.zip
```

Does this help your problem?